# What is the best flow for Angular2 application and asp.net core 2.0 api

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi

I am having a asp.net core 2.0 webapi and pure angular2 application. I am using Identityserver4 for implementing OpenId and OAuth2 for securing the webapi.

Can anyone suggest what is the best flow to implement the angular2 client application?

Thanks

Comment: A lot will depend on your specific need.  Why do you need Angular? Since Asp. Net can do frontEnd as well? That will answer what the Angular role is...

Comment: OIDC Implicit flow

Answer (score 3):

Implicit flow using the oidc-client-js library to do the dirty work.

https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js

The library can do nice things like session monitoring and automatic renewal of access tokens.

Comment: Here is a link to implement silent refresh of the tokens since Implicit Flow does not allow renewal of tokens.https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenID-Connect/Silent-Refresh-Refreshing-Access-Tokens-when-using-the-Implicit-Flow